# Можно ли показывать свою рекламу в приложении?

Tags: appstore, android, ios, iphone

Собственно сабж.
Вопрос относится как к iOS, так и Android.

Могу ли я показывать в своем приложении свою собственную баннерную рекламу?
Без iAd, admob и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS — нет, что и неудивительно, в общем-то.
Android — да, можете.

Comment: можете поделиться материалом про iOS?

Comment: Насколько я помню, там запрещено использование всего, что не включено в список *supported ad networks*, а список этот не слишком велик. Конкретной ссылкой поделиться не могу, ибо сходу не нагуглилось.

Answer (score 0):

конечно, никто вроде не запрещает.

по крайней мере в наших игрушках/приложениях встроена своя система кросспромо, которая позволяет рекламировать свои же игры/приложения и которая успешно работает уже несколько месяцев. да и потом в инете полно сервисов, построенных по тому же принципу. (например в статье на хабре описан один из [сервисов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/188132/))

Answer (score 0):

кросспромо своих же приложений в айоси проходит - и у нас как-то был такой финт, да и у других видел, у того же яндекса например. Другой вопрос что сегодня оно прошло, а завтра попался другой цензор и все - нельзя. На хабре кто-то даже писал что то же самое развернутое цензором приложение переименовывали, посылали заново на апрув и оно проходило

Answer (score 0):

Сам с этим не сталкивался, но думаю можно, если переопределить нужные методы в фреймворке iAd.

Answer (score 0):

Такой себе "хак".(Не кидайтесь кирпичами, если не прав. Не слишком знаком с процедурой аппрува для iOS. Просто идея.)  
Встраиваем рекламу, которая должна отображаться в том случае, если сервер разрешает. И на сервере запрещаем показ до тех пор, пока приложение не пройдет апрув. Эта штука работает только в том случае, если цензура не имеет доступа к исходному коду(а я почти уверен, что не имеет)

Comment: А потом это, рано или поздно, всё же замечают, и получаем бан аккаунта разработчика.

Comment: думаю, даже если имеет то не смотрит его, хотя за такие шутки можно и аккаунт разработчика потерять за нарушения